# Python thread or process model where child thread or process can survive parent?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

This is a design question in reference to python scripting in using threads versus multi-processes.  As I understand it, spawning a thread using the threading module cannot survive termination of the the parent thread, i.e. process.  The parent thread must either do a join (i.e. wait timeout not withstanding) or exit, if no join, on parent exit the child threads are terminated.  This is due to the shared resources model of threads, right?

Whereas the multiprocessing module when a process is spawned it can survive, i.e. continue to completion, regardless if the parent process which created it exits or terminates.  This assumes of course that the parent process never called a join for the child process to complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, `threading` and `multiprocessing` are designed to achieve parallelism within a program. Their goal is not to launch independent processes. Hence both packages implicitly terminate their parallel execution paths during preparation for interpreter shutdown.

Threads are subsets of processes, they cannot outlive the process that created them.
Active non daemonic threads are implicitly joined upon interpreter shutdown using the function [`_shutdown()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/threading.py#L1263) in the threading module. This function is [called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6a150bcaeb190d1731b38ab9c7a5d1a352847ddc/Python/pylifecycle.c#L2227) during the finalization routine in the Python interpreter lifecycle.
Daemonic threads simply end with the interpreter process.

If processes, created via `multiprocessing`, are still alive when the interpreter prepares to shut down, they are terminated by the [`_exit_function()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L285), that has been [registered as exit handler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/util.py#L327) via [atexit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html). Similar to `threading`, `multiprocessing` joins non daemonic child processes; on daemonic childs, `terminate()` is called.

If you want to launch processes from a Python program and have that program exit afterwards, use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen). If you are on a POSIX platform, you might also want to take a look at [`python-daemon`](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/).

Comment: Thanks for the very nice explanation.  I guess I could also use a variant os.fork as well, but that is not an elegant solution at all, and has its own issues as well.